# Java Heap Space Error | Doubly linked lists

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

The goal of program is to create two doubly linked list, reading numbers from a file and adding them together, creating a new doubly linked list and printing the result. Running it, I am presented with the error, 
Java lang out of memory: java heap space error

I am relatively new to data structures and coding, and cannot figure out what is causing this error. Currently thinking that it is somewhere in my loop, creating extra nodes in an infinite loop. (Included the loop with the error, not full code).

```
int sum = 0;
  Digit endHead = new Digit(); //summed linked list
  Digit endCurr = endHead;
  Digit endPrev = endHead;
  while (true)
  {
      if (currOne == null && currTwo == null) //ex. at the end of addition carrying the last number.
      {
          sum = sum;
      }
      else if (currOne == null)
      {
          sum = currTwo.value + sum;
      }

      else if (currTwo == null)
      {
          sum = currOne.value + sum;
      }
      else
      {
          sum = currOne.value + currTwo.value + sum;  
      }

      endCurr.value = sum % 10; //to get the number to carry over
      sum = sum / 10; //to get the ones place

      if (currOne == null && currTwo == null && sum == 0)
      {
          break;
      }
      else
      {
          endCurr.next = new Digit();
          endCurr = endCurr.next;
          endCurr.prev = endPrev;
          endPrev = endCurr;
      }  
  }
```

Comment: I would say to use the debugger and walk through your program, and while a debugger is definitely something you want to begin to learn, if you're new to programming then you could just use a simple ```System.out.println``` to test it out. What I would do is put a print statement at the end of the loop and see what prints out. My guess is that you're never hitting 0, therefore you're never hitting your break statement.

Comment: Nothing in this code sets or updates currOne or currTwo. The code is going to run forever, creating a new `Digit` object every time and adding it to the `endHead` chain, so every `Digit` will always be referenced by `endHead` so cannot be garbage collected.